# How to take first letter from C string?

Tags: c, string, variables, char, scanf

I want to take the first letter from my firstname string variable and add it to the second letter of the lastname variable.

My program so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
char firstname [256];
char lastname [256];
printf("What's your first name?: ");
scanf("%c",&firstname);
printf("What is your last name? ");
scanf("%s",&lastname);
printf("\nYour school.edu e-mail address is: %c%s2@school.edu",firstname,lastname);
return 0;
}
```

However, I would like for my code to take the first initial (the first letter of the first name) and store it into the firstname variable.

Comment: Are you facing problem in accessing a array element or overwriting in a existing array?

Comment: Why are you having an array of 256 chars for "firstname" when you are only interested in and storing the first character?

Comment: Kindly post the expected input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

As strings are array of characters, you need to take the first element from the array:

```
char firstname_initial;
firstname_initial = firstname[0]
```

Also note that since `lastname` and `firstname` are buffers, you don't need to pass a pointer to them in `scanf`:

```
scanf( "%s", firstname );
scanf( "%s", lastname );
```

And one last thing - `scanf` is a dangerous function and you should not use it.

Comment: Now I get the error: subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer

Comment: Got rid of the error. However now when I type in firstname it just goes firstname2@school.edu without even asking me to scan a second name and it doesnt take any intials

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the user types:

```
Michael
```

in response to the first prompt.  The `%c` format reads the `M`; the `%s` format reads `ichael` without bothering to get any new data.

Also, you should not be passing `&firstname` or `&lastname`; you should be passing just `firstname` and `lastname` to `scanf()`.  The difference is in the type; with the ampersand, you're passing a `char (*)[256]` which is not the same as the `char *` that `scanf()` expects.  You get away with it, but 'get away with it' is the operative term.

Use a `%s` format (or, better, `%255s` format) for the two `scanf()` calls.  Then pass `firstname[0]` and `lastname` to `printf()`.  You might want to think about using `tolower()` from `<ctype.h>` on the first letter, and maybe on the last name too.

This is a reasonable approximation to a good program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char firstname[256];
    char lastname[256];
    printf("What's your first name? ");
    if (scanf("%255s", firstname) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("What's your last  name? ");
    if (scanf("%255s", lastname) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Your school.edu e-mail address is: %c%s2@school.edu\n",
           firstname[0], lastname);
    return 0;
}
```

It avoids quite a lot of problems, one way or another.  It is not completely foolproof, but most people won't run into problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the variable **firstname** to store only the initial.
So that **firstname** act like string.

```
firstname[1] = '\0'; //mark the end of string on second character
printf("\nYour school.edu e-mail address is: %s%s2@school.edu",firstname,lastname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main() {
char firstname [256];
char lastname [256];
char str [50];
printf("What's your first name?: ");
scanf("%s",firstname);
printf("What is your last name? ");
scanf("%s",lastname);
str = strcpy(str, firstname[0]);
str = strcpy(str,lastname[1]);
printf("\nYour school.edu e-mail address is: %s2@school.edu",str);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have various problems. You can't copy `firstname[0]` like that with `strcpy()`. You also can't do it with `lastname[1]`, and you probably don't want to do it anyway (`lastname` or `&lastname[0]` instead).  You allocated 50 bytes for the composite name, but 256 for the last name; this could lead to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming expected input:

```
fname = Batman
lname = Joker
```

Expected Output:

```
Your school.edu e-mail address is: BJBker2@school.edu
```

Try this:

```
void main( void )
{
char fname = 0;
char lname[256] = {0};

printf("Enter firstname\n");
scanf("%c", &fname);

printf("Enter lastname\n");
scanf("%s", lname);

lname[1] = fname;

printf("Your school.edu e-mail address is: %c%s2@school.edu\n", fname, lname);

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy first char from c string**

```
char extractedchar = '0';
extractedchar=myoldstring[0];
```

Note : the char '0' is there just to test later in the application